# How can I compare against a possibly null value in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, null, where-clause

I see a number of variations on this question but they all seem to talk about performance and indexes when asking about comparing null values.

My issue is that I have a nested SELECT that can return null that I am comparing against based on a date parameter.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Table_One a,
     Table_Two b
WHERE a.Fieldc IN (SELECT CompareValue from Table_Three cv WHERE inDate between cv.Date_ and SYSDATE)
AND a.Fielda = b.Fieldb(+)
```

it seems like when the nested select here returns null then the left join messes up.

I'll be happy to include some fake data if it's needed but maybe I'm just missing something.
 What I need to have occur is that the Fieldc comparison only occurs within that date specification.

Thanks for any insight.
Thanks.

Further information:

Table_One Data: all fields are varchar2

```
Fielda | Fieldb | Fieldc|
'aVal' | 'bVal' | 'cVal'|
'dVal' | 'eVal  | 'fVal'|
'dVal' | 'fVal  | 'eVal'|
```

Table_Two Data: all fields are varchar2

```
Fielda | Fieldb | Fieldc|
'aVal' | 'bVal' | 'cVal'|
'dVal' | 'fVal  | 'gVal'|
'dVal' | 'fVal  | 'cVal'|
```

Table_Three Data: CompareValue is varchar2, date_ is date

```
CompareValue | date_      |
'fval'       | 2012-09-10 |
```

So if the parameter were today the select returns 'fval' and we get left join correctly. however, when the date parameter is before '2012-09-10' then the nested select is comparing a null and the left join does not happen properly. This is a bit of a simplified version of the original.

Thanks

Comment: do you want it to match when the value is null or not match?

Comment: It's not clear to me from the query why the left outer join is needed at all.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but nonetheless: don't use the `(+)` operator for outer joins. Use a proper `LEFT JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Left join "messes up" is not terribly informative. What exactly does that mean? Error codes? If the subquery returns null, what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 6):

use `NVL(inDate, sysdate+1)` to not match when null

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are selecting from table a on the condition that a.Fieldc is considered "active", because in table_three it's inDate lies between some start date and sysdate.

Therefore I don't think you want to always have a result. Instead I'd advise you to handle an empty result in your code.

I'm afraid I cannot give a more precise answer, because you haven't shared any more information about your case.

Comment: Bazz you are correct, I'm matching on a value in table_three when active by date. I'm including extra info in my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between `No records` and `Null` values. When you say - "when the date parameter is before '2012-09-10' then the nested select is comparing a null and the left join does not happen properly", this means the `SELECT` returns a row but the row value is `NULL` (this is not same as No records). In this case, doing an `NVL` on the `NULL` column value and replacing it with a fake string (as you said) would work like-

```
SELECT NVL(CompareValue,'dummy') 
  from Table_Three cv WHERE inDate between cv.Date_ and SYSDATE
```

The above would return `dummy` if `CompareValue` is `NULL` but not if the query returns NO RECORDS at all.

However, looking at your data, I do not see a possibility of a NULL value which leads me to believe that the subquery will actually return NO RECORDS (not same as `NULL`) if `inDate` is before 2012-09-10. In this case your query should be perfectly fine (unless there is something else going wrong somewhere else).